# How to save a bundle directory to NSTemporaryDirectory()

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

Is it possible to copy a bundled directory (Website structure) to NSTemporaryDirectory by using the NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath or I need to do a recursive function to copy file by file?

I'm targeting iOS 8 and 9 and I'm using Swift 2.

I searched on Google but everything I found is about a single file copy but nothing about a complete folder structure from the bundle to the app container.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation for `copyItemAtPath(_:error:)`?

> If the item at srcPath is a directory, this method copies the directory and all of its contents, including any hidden files.

Comment: Yes I read this part, but when I was testing it I received no errors but the files were not in the destination path. I'll try to copy them in ApplicationSupport instead of the NSTemporaryDirectory just to be sure.

Comment: Providing what you tried and what results you saw (including how you knew the files were not in the destination path) is critical to us helping you. The question of whether this function copies directories is yes. You have some other problem specific to your use.